# refused to display in a frame in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I am trying to embed a google doc into an iframe. I am using javascript to create iframes in a loop for each spreadsheet there is in my folder.

I can manage this for my other page but in this page I use the same code and I get this error

Refused to display 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/19CykhheCl1XUjdmY3-MNAIxX-YCNzbfbALdgdj8FvrY/edit?usp=sharing' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

```
var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($fileList ); ?>; 

    for(x=0; x<jArray.length; x++){

        var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
        var ifrmVal = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/19CykhheCl1XUjdmY3-MNAIxX-YCNzbfbALdgdj8FvrY/edit?usp=sharing";                   

        ifrm.setAttribute("src",ifrmVal);
        ifrm.style.width = 1000+"px"; 
        ifrm.style.height = 120+"px"; 

        ifrm.setAttribute("frameborder", 0);
        ifrm.setAttribute("name", "theframe");
        document.getElementById('content').appendChild(ifrm);   
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. the Googles response header has X-Frame-Options set to SAMEORIGIN meaning that you can access google only from some other page hosted on google.com and not from anywhere else.

Comment: That is not true, I am able to embed google documents using this but now it doesnt work in this page yet it does on my other page.

Comment: Can you please share the url of the page, where you are able to embed the google document. Ideally this is impossible, unless you are using a very old browser which cannot understand the X-Frame-Options response header.

Comment: I think you did not get the point. When you try to open this (docs.google.com/....) url from the address bar of your browser, it will work.

But when you use it as part of the src attribute for an iframe, **it will not work.

This is part of the security mechanism introduced by modern browsers.**

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options